# Postfix: Blocking connections on submission port based on geoip

Tags: postfix, firewall

Currently I'm reducing failed authentication spam in logs by blocking access to Dovecot and SSHD based on the IP address country of origin. Both services require authentication and I have no users or automation needing access, outside a rather small list of countries.

This is done using a tcpwrappers' `aclcheck` and a shell script being passed `%a` and invoking `geoiplookup` (or `geoiplookup6`) binary that I happen to have installed on my system. All set up with `/etc/hosts.allow`, `/etc/hosts.deny`.

This is enough to get rid of most failed logins.

Postfix, despite being authored by the same person as tcpwrappers, does not do tcpwrappers -- at least in Debian, its various binaries are not linked against `libwrap.so`.

`iptables` is, to my knowledge, not applicable; I don't believe it can ask a userspace binary to determine whether an IP packet (such as TCP SYN) should be accepted or rejected.

---

Is there a convenient way to either make Postfix's daemons that listen for TCP connections, such as `master`, make use of `hosts.allow`/`hosts.deny`? Is `tcpd` an answer? How would one make proper use of it?

I'm interested in blocking just the `smtps` and `submission` ports -- those that allow authentication (and thus allow post-authentication relaying) -- based on the country of origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `iptables` is, to my knowledge, not applicable; I don't believe it can ask a userspace binary to determine whether an IP packet (such as TCP SYN) should be accepted or rejected.

Actually you can use the netfilter (`iptables`) NFQUEUE to have an external program evaluate packets/connections.

I'm usually on RHEL and CentOS and download the ip-ranges in CIDR format and then [use `ipset` to create a relatively efficient white- or blacklist in `iptables`](https://serverfault.com/a/714498/37681).

But when you're on for instance Debian/Ubuntu you can easily install the [`xt_geoip`](http://xtables-addons.sourceforge.net/geoip.php) module from the package xtables-addons-dkms to get GeoIP capabilities for your netfilter iptables firewall:

Install the package:

```
apt-get install xtables-addons-dkms
```

Download the Geo IP source data and build the binary database:

```
mkdir /usr/share/xt_geoip
cd mkdir /usr/share/xt_geoip
/var/lib/dkms/xtables-addons/2.12/build/geoip/xt_geoip_dl
/var/lib/dkms/xtables-addons/2.12/build/geoip/xt_geoip_build -D /usr/share/xt_geoip GeoIPCountryWhois.csv GeoIPv6.csv
```

And then add country aware geoip firewall rules as needed:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m geoip  --src-cc NL,UK  -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

of if you prefer:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m geoip  ! --src-cc NL,UK  -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j REJECT
```